# Fedora and Windows dual-boot boots to grub command line

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, dualboot

I'm trying to dual boot fedora34 and windows 10, but ran into some issues installing fedora. I followed this tutorial to install fedora34 to dual-boot with win10 which was already installed on my pc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln8z3pBOpN0 After the installation when I rebooted it boots into the grub command line and not fedora. ls shows (proc) and 4 (hd0,gpt) partitions. (my pc is uefi btw) doing ls on gpt1 says its formatted in Fat, ls on proc says the pc is running procfs or something I forgot but its not important. ls on any other partition says it's an unknown file system. if I type exit it takes me to the windows bootloader where I can boot into win10, or "linux" which is the grub command line. If that part sounds weird I messed with the boot loader previously. This would seem easier if it weren't for the partitions saying unknown file system. By the way, fedora is on an sd card but the boot partition is on the computers hard drive. Thanks,